# Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range -Error

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, runtime-error

I am running VBA in excel in order to do some web-scraping, but am coming up with this error when attempting to reach Google Chrome. How would one avoid this? I will click debug then a single line becomes highlighted...

This is where the error pops up

[image: This is where the error pops up]

This is the highlighted line of code that must be giving the issue

[image: This is the highlighted line of code that must be giving the issue]

[Full Code in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr2Dw.jpg)

**FULL CODE BELOW:**

```
Private Sub time_sheet_filling()

    Dim I As Long
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("ChromeTab.ChromeFrame")
    IE.Visible = True

    ' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
    IE.navigate "https://wistar.dispondo.net/#/login"

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

        'Load the logon page
    Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    I = 0
    While I < objCollection.Length
        If objCollection(I).Name = "username" Then
            ' Set text to enter
            objCollection(I).Value = "MyUsername"
        End If
        If objCollection(I).Name = "password" Then
            ' Set text for password
            objCollection(I).Value = "MyPasword"
        End If
        If objCollection(I).Type = "submit" And objCollection(I).Name = "btnSubmit" Then ' submit button clicking
            Set objElement = objCollection(I)
        End If
        I = I + 1
    Wend

    objElement.Click    ' click button to load the form

    ' Wait while IE re-loading...
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    ' Show IE
    IE.Visible = True
Dim links, link
Dim n, j
Set links = IE.Document.getElementById("dgTime").getElementsByTagName("a")
n = links.Length
For j = 0 To n - 1 Step 2
    links(j).Click
'I have some operations to be done will post another question for this

Next



End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: Code in image <> code in text! `Debug.print Chromepath & Sheets...`an see the missing blank after`chrome.exe"`(except there is a (surprising) starting blank in the cell).

Answer (score 1):

That error would occur if there is not a worksheet named "Website Data" in the active workbook at the time of the code running. Either the worksheet name does not match, or a different workbook is active when the code is running.

Make sure the worksheet name is correct and also explicitly reference the workbook it is located in (so that it doesn't matter which workbook is active when the code is running). If the "Website Data" sheet is in the workbook where the code is running, then refer to the value in the cell using:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Website Data").Cells(1,1).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Chrome instead of IE in this way. Chrome can only use via Selenium for web scraping via VBA. The IE is the only browser with a COM Interface which is needed to control an application via VBA:

For more information:

[About the Component Object Model (COM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model)

[About Selenium browser automation](https://selenium.dev/)